# Permanently disable previews in Slack

Tags: slack

How can I disable image and video previews in Slack? I've found the `/collapse` command, but that only seems to collapse existing media in the current channel. What I want is for future ones not to preview at all.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

On the browser view, click on the drop down menu next to your team's name on  *Preferences*. Then click on *Messages and media* on the left-hand side. Then, under the section **Inline Media & Links** you will find checkboxes for

- Expand images and files uploaded to Slack
- Expand links to images, video and audio from external sources

  - Even if it is an image larger than 2MB
- Expand website links to show a preview of the content, when available

Uncheck whichever of those that you want and you are set!

Comment: This also works in the slack app on mac.

Comment: Can this be done at a team / organization level for all users? Also is it possible to selectively do this for certain domains?

Comment: What does this do, exactly? Does it change how my client changes my inbound messages? What I _want_ to do is change how other people see my outbound messages, so I'm not spamming them with walls of link previews.

Comment: @jameshfisher Yes, it's purely client-side.  The actual message content is unchanged and doesn't include any preview information in either case (I have been playing with the API recently).  Your recipients will have to turn it off if they don't want the previews.