# How do I re-enable link previews in Slack?

Tags: slack

At some point I disabled website link previews from YouTube in our Slack team. But this was a huge mistake, we need them back. How do I re-enable link previews for a specific website that was disabled, or for all websites?

I have already disabled / re-enabled all preview types under Preferences > Messages & Media, but YouTube is still disabled.

Comment: [This question](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/76084/354) has the opposite problem, but it looks like the answer may provide a clue for you.

Answer (score 12):

Visit https://[TEAM].slack.com/admin/attachments as an admin or owner of the team. Then simply click the X on all the website link previews you want to automatically "unfurl" again.

[image: Slack Blacklisted Attachments]

Answer (score -2):

There is no way to do this right now. I don't think Slack has built this feature.