# Reenable unfurling (expanding) of media and attachments in Slack

Tags: slack

In Slack (at least in their Mac app)<sup>1</sup>, you can click on the `x` button on the left side of an inline media (unfurled attachment) and close it.

When you do so, Slack shows a dialog and asks you if "Are you sure you wish to remove this attachment from the message?" and there is an checkbox that gives you the option to "Disable future attachments from this website?".

I checked that box an permanently disabled expansion of media from a certain domain. But now I want them back, but cannot find a way to do so.

So basically, I want to re-enable expansion of inline media for URLs from a domain I disabled through that dialog.

---

<sup>1</sup> It is not a native client problem. The same story holds for the web client or the Mac or iOS clients. I actually tried them all.

Comment: Yes, same issue in the web client, Basically the mac client is a wrapper around the web client, but yet, I opened it in Chrome and same story.

Comment: I looked all through my profile settings and couldn't find anything. Then again, I am using Slack for Teams.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/97579/how-do-i-re-enable-link-previews-in-slack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find the list of blacklisted links in the Admin Settings > Attachments tab.

Answer (score -1):

For the link unfurl, I found this setting at `/apps/manage/mutes` which I got to by choosing Administration > Manage Apps from the Slack App and then choosing "Muted Apps" in the left sidebar.