# Permanently expand Slack messages

Tags: slack

I am receiving messages on Slack from Jenkins via the [Slack Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Slack+Plugin). I noticed that the message body is collapsed when it gets to a certain length as shown in the screenshot.

[image: Jenkins - Slack message[2]]

I would like to expand these messages by default because I cannot see what happened on Jenkins. I have to manually click on "Show more..." for every message.

I am using the Slack App for Mac v.2.6.3. I could not find a setting in the preferences.

## Related questions

- [Permanently disable previews in Slack](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/76084/permanently-disable-previews-in-slack)

Comment: You can probably only do this via a userscript (at least via the web interface - you may be able to do something similar for the app). I don't use Slack so I can't really help you, but essentially you can use something like GreaseMonkey and have a script check for posts from Jenkins, auto-clicking the "show more" button then

Comment: I am aware of GreaseMonkey as an browser addon and I use it for other websites. In this case however I use the **Slack MacOS app**. I am not aware that I can use GreaseMonkey for a standalone app.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of the Jenkins plugin is using a block kit based interface and it is free from the issues described above.